# how to understand that the session is closed

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

After a forced stop job in dbms_sheduler session some time remains active, although the job has been stopped. How do you know that the session is closed, do not use v$session views.

I stop all jbos as

```
   FOR r IN (SELECT JOB_CLASS FROM JBSD$SCHEDULER_JOBS) LOOP
      dbms_scheduler.disable(name => 'SYS.'||r.JOB_CLASS, force => TRUE);
      dbms_scheduler.stop_job(job_name => 'SYS.'||r.JOB_CLASS, force => TRUE);
   END LOOP;
```

and throws an exception in function run the job to interrupt her

Comment: What is the version up to four decimals?

Comment: Version is 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: Set the trace on and see what exactly is going in the trace file.

Comment: Thank you all, in the end, decided to look at the session through v$session view.